# Proving independence of $A,B$ and $C$ in probability theory

Tags: probability

If $A$ is independent of $B$ and $B$ is independent of $C$, then $A$ is independent of
$C$. Prove this statement or give a counterexample if it is false.

What i tried

Form the drawing of the Venn diagram, i know intuitively that  if $A$ is independent of $B$ and $B$ is independent of $C$ then $A$ is not necessarily independent of $C$ and the statement is false and i need to disprove the above statement. So my approach is the i would assume that the statement is true and arrive at a contradiction somehow.

Rewriting the above statement in symbolic form,

if $$P(A ∩ B)=P(A).P(B)$$

and

$$P(B ∩ C)=P(B).P(C)$$

then we would get

$$P(A ∩ C)=P(A).P(C)$$

We then need to somehow arrive at a contradiction.
I tried rewriting all 3 equations to get if $$P(A)+P(B)-P(A ∪ B)=P(A).P(B)$$
and $$P(B)+P(C)-P(B ∪ C)=P(B).P(C)$$then $$P(A)+P(C)-P(A ∪ C)=P(A).P(C)$$
Then the next step is to combine all the 3 equations together and them simplifying it. Could anyone explain. Thanks

Comment: To disprove the statement you need a counterexample, not a general proof.

Comment: Oh but why cant i use contradiction to disprove it?

Comment: To answer your 'why can't I' question: Independence of $A$ and $C$ might happen SOME  of the time - so the algebra might not forbid it. (i.e., it can happen that $1+ x = 1$, but only if $x=0$, and not if $x=3$, say.) On the other hand, you can try a specific counter example to show that the property doesn't hold ALL of the time.  For instance take $C = A$. Then $ A \cap C = A$, but usually $P( A ) \not = P(A)\cdot P(A)$. To make life easy, take $B=\emptyset$, and $A$ such that $P(A)= 1/2$.

Comment: Okay thanks. I understood already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about: Experiment is to roll a die twice.

A: You get doubles (same value twice)

B: Your first roll is $3$

C: The sum is $7$